# WCF TestClient Error if calling Get() methods

Tags: wcf

I'm dealing with a problem with WCF Testing. I have a **CategorieService** WCF service.. See the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wbg1.jpg  sharing it through *netTcpBinding* Everything it's ok(all methods are being called properly) except the GetAll() GetById() methods. It throws an exception... See the details https://i.stack.imgur.com/I60vt.jpg

Here is the *App.config* file

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
        logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
      <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <services>
      <service name="Services.CategorieService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
          listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/myservice" binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="Services.ICategorieService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: It seems your methods GetAll and GetById doesn't respond in time, do they? Try to check it and if its true = try to increase timeout in client config file. Or optimize queries

Comment: It could also be due to an error in the service itself -check the service to see if there are any obvious places an error may be occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using POCO entities with a DbContext connection. The ProxyCreation option must be set to `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`